# Function returns wrong value when invoked let variable = function()

Tags: javascript, function

Basically, if an `index` is equal to 0, I want it to `return 1` and if it's equal to `1` I want it to`return 0`

So I created this.

```
let reverseIndex = function() {
  console.log(timeIndex) // 1
  let i
  timeIndex === 0 ? i = 1 : i = 0
  return i
}()

function getDiff(time) {
  console.log(reverseIndex) // 1 (WRONG)
}
```

But if I change the function to include ONLY

```
function getDiff(time) {
  let i
  timeIndex === 0 ? i = 1 : i = 0
  console.log(i) // 0 (CORRECT)
}
```

Comment: What is `timeIndex` inside function?

Comment: why did you put () after function rather than putting it in function call ?

Comment: There are so many things wrong here it's hard to know where to even start asking questions...

Comment: @JaredSmith can you explain?

Comment: Also why not just `return timeIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0` or even `return +(timeIndex === 0)`?

Comment: This whole thing is a huge convoluted mess. To crib from nina scholtz's answer you could replace all of that with `reverseIndex = +!timeIndex;` (or Andrew Li's slightly longer version). You are asking us to debug your rube-goldberg machine...

Comment: Is this a typo: `console.log(reverseIndex)` ? This does not invoke your function. You want `console.log(reverseIndex())`

Comment: @JonB No. It's an IIFE...

Comment: @AndrewLi - thanks - I missed the `()` at the end there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an assignment with the ternary statement?

```
let i = timeIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

shorter with a truty/falsy value, a conversion to boolean and a conversion to number of the boolean.

```
let i = +!timeIndex;
```

Or simply return the value without using a temporary variable

```
return +!timeIndex;
```

Comment: Why use `i` at all?

Comment: Because I didn't want to change timeIndex

Comment: @dsomel21 it doesn't.

Comment: @JaredSmith I thought it did.

Comment: @dsomel21 the unary not operator `!` returns a boolean that is the logical inverse of its operand (in this case, an integer). They aren't even the same *type*, so how would any mutation be happening?

Comment: `timeIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;` Will that not change the original value of timeIndex?

Comment: `timeIndex` is just used, it is not changed. there is no assignment in this expression.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be careful about the scope of your variables. Where is `timeIndex` defined?

The simplest function to get the right result would be

```
function reverse(i) {
  if (i==0) return 1;
  if (i==1) return 0;
}
```